# "Submitted URL not found (404)" Submitted where?

Tags: seo, google

Inside the Google search console it's showing an error with the code

"Submitted URL not found (404)"

We can click on the little zooming glass to get more details about where the page was submitted (sitemaps, internal link etc).

When I do that it shows no internal source as below

[image]

So I'm trying to understand the "Submitted URL" part and where I can "unsubmit" it since it's not in the sitemaps and has no internal links..

The page has a proper 404 code, so it shouldn't be crawling it either.

Comment: I was going to say maybe it was submitted through the pubic URL submission tool, but Google took that down in July 2018.  [Google Removes Public URL Submission Tool - Search Engine Journal](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-removes-public-url-submission-tool/263271/#close)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller hmm it could be that! this URL dates back from a while ago actually. At least beginning of 2018